# The Show function in jquery not working on chrome mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form HTML and jQuery AJAX:

```js
$('#form_question').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'validate_question.php',
    data: formData,
    success: function(response) {
      var correctLabel = $('label[for="' + response.correct_answer + '"]');
      correctLabel.addClass('correct-answer');
      if (response.message == 'Réponse correcte') {
        $('#form_question').hide();
        $('#win').show();
      }
      if (response.message == 'Réponse incorrecte') {
        $('#loose').show();
      }
      if (response.message == 'Cette question a déjà été répondue.') {
        $('#form_question').hide();
        $('#already_answered').show();
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.error(xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="form-question" method="post" action="validate_question.php" id="form_question">
  <div>
    <h1 class="mt-1 mb-4 text-center">
      <?= $data['question']; ?>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="loose" style="display: none;">
    <?php include 'templates/not_correct.php';  ?>
  </div>
  <div>
    <?php foreach ($data['propositions'] as $key => $proposition): ?>
    <div class="option">
      <input type="radio" id="<?= $key; ?>" name="option" value="<?= $key; ?>">
      <label for="<?= $key; ?>"><?= $proposition; ?></label>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-button" id="validateButtonWrapper">
    <input type="hidden" name="code_step" value="<?= $code_step; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id_team" value="<?= $check_password['id']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="validateButton" class="btn btn-primary" value="Valider" />
  </div>
</form>
<div id="win" style="display: none;">
  <?php include 'templates/correct.php';  ?>
</div>

<div id="already_answered" style="display: none;">
  <?php include 'templates/already_answered.php';  ?>
</div>
```

I have this PHP code validate_question.php to treat the form

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Dotenv\Dotenv;
$dotenvPath = __DIR__;
$dotenv = Dotenv::createImmutable($dotenvPath);
$dotenv->load();

require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

$response_data = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['option'])) {
    // get response of question 
    $response = $_POST['option'];
    $code_step = $_POST['code_step'] ? $_POST['code_step'] : NULL;
    $id_team = $_POST['id_team'] ? $_POST['id_team'] : NULL;
    $id_step = get_id_step_by_code($db, $code_step);
    $already_answered = check_step_team($db, $id_team, $id_step['id']);

    if (NULL !== $response) {
        if (!$already_answered) {
            if (NULL !== $id_step && NULL !== $code_step) {
                // check if response correct
                $result = get_answer_by_step($db, $code_step, $response);            
                if ($result['is_answer_correct']) { 
                    $response_data['success'] = true;
                    $response_data['message'] = 'Réponse correcte';
                    $response_data['correct_answer'] = $result['correct_answer'];
                    record_step_for_team($id_team, $code_step, $db);
                } else {
                    $response_data['success'] = false;
                    $response_data['message'] = 'Réponse incorrecte';
                    $response_data['correct_answer'] = $result['correct_answer'];
                    record_step_for_team($id_team, $code_step, $db, false);
                }
            } else {
                $response_data['success'] = false;
                $response_data['message'] = 'Aucune réponse reçue.';
            }
        } else {
            $response_data['success'] = false;
            $response_data['message'] = 'Cette question a déjà été répondue.';
        }
    } else {
        $response_data['success'] = false;
        $response_data['message'] = 'Aucune réponse reçue.';
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode('erreur');
}
echo json_encode($response_data);
?>
```

When I validate the form, I have a page with my div id = win (or already_answered) BUT It works only on desktop or on firefox or brave browser but it does not work on Chrome mobile.
Don't understand why ?
Thanks for your answers

EDIT
This is an image to show what is displaying on chrome mobile (json brut):
[image]

Comment: I suggest you use numeric error codes instead of comparing the messages. Maybe there's a character set problem.

Comment: I change and do this : $response_data['return_code'] = 1; and if (response.return_code == 1)  for example but It does not change anything I have still the json brut display in chrome mobile

Comment: I would normally suggest using DevTools to debug this, but that's not available in mobile chrome so I'm not sure how to figure it out. You can try `alert(JSON.stringify(response))`.

Comment: It does not work either. No alert is displaying and I have still the brut json

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "brut json".

Comment: Sorry I have the alert displaying for example "{success:"false", "return_code":3}. I add an image to my first message to show what I mean by "brut json"

Comment: That should match `if (response.message == 'Cette question a déjà été répondue.')`

Comment: The content of the div "win" is displayed when I am on desktop or in other browser than Chrome on mobile. But on chrome I have the "brut json" like my image in my first message.

Comment: Now I understand -- the form is being submitted and you're seeing the JSON answer in the web page. So for some reason either the `.submit()` function isn't running or `e.preventDefault()` isn't working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257256/discussion-between-barmar-and-chtouk).